# Three minute delay for sonar-runner "Store results in database" (jdbc/mysql)

Tags: mysql, jdbc, sonar-runner

Storing a sonar-runner report in the sonar server MySQL database takes 3 minutes. It establishes a db connection quick enough, and it says it stored the report in 213 ms, but it takes 3+ minutes to get done. I seems as if it waits 3 minutes (for some timeout?) after it's done the inserts. Any way to fix this?

This is what sonar-runner says:

```
...
20:30:32.973 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
20:30:33.037 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://n.n.n.n:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
20:30:36.463 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
...
20:31:13.033 INFO  - Execute decorators...
20:31:20.178 INFO  - Store results in database
20:34:21.505 INFO  - Analysis reports generated in 64ms, dir size=47 KB
20:34:21.551 INFO  - Analysis reports compressed in 46ms, zip size=36 KB
20:34:21.764 INFO  - Analysis reports sent to server in 213ms
...
```

As you can see from the timestamps, it takes 3 minutes and 1 second to store data, and sonar-runner says it sent it in 213ms.

The only uncommented line in sonar-runner.properties is:

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://n.n.n.n:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
```

The client is running OS X, and I can ssh to the server without noticeable delays.

The server is an AWS Ubuntu image with a plain (apt-get) MySQL 5.6 installation. The only change in my.cnf is chaning bind address from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

could maybe be a problem on non-closed connections or non commited transactions to the db that can block your transaction for a while?

Check that
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/31/how-to-analyze-innodb-mysql-locks/

Hope it helps